# How to make a static carousel with different image sizes without breaking responsivness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am beginner in front end web development. My goal is to make a carousel which has images taken from google with different sizes, make the carousel have the dimensions of the biggest image and all of this without breaking reponsivnes

So here is an example:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image1.jpg" alt="Image from google">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item">
      <img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image2.jpg" alt="Image from google">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image3.jpg" alt="Image from google">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

If there is no default or easy way to do this, I would like to write a function in javascript/JQuery like the below Pseudo code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#myCarousel').carousel();
      myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
  var biggestWidth;
  var biggestHeight;
  var dimensionsArr;
  for each Image class object {

    //get the size array
    dimensionsArr = getSize(Image);

  //if biggest dimenensons are null then assign the first one
    if (biggestWidth = null && biggestHeight = null){
      biggestWidth = dimensionsArr[0];
      biggestHeight = dimensionsArr[1];
    }else{
      biggestWidth = ifBigger(dimensionsArr[0],biggestWidth);
      biggestHeight = ifBIgger(dimensionsArr[1],biggestHeight);
    }

    //Next i want to display the carousel in the way it would scale
    //on the device (or parent element) with the biggest image, but for all images. Ofcourse the biggest image should scale to width of the parent element of the carousel as well like it is by default
  }
}

function getSize(Image image) {
  var widthHeight;
  Get the size of the image

  //This would be an array [width, height]
  return widthHeight
}

//the function determines if new dimension is bigger or old biggest
// and return the bigger one
function ifBigger(newSize,biggestSize) {
  if(newSize > biggestSize) {
     return newSize;
     }
  else() {
    return biggestSize;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This css should help. It will make all images same height and width regardless of their dimensions but yeah, images might appear stretched in some cases. adjust the percentage to get the aspect ratio you want. this one is 56.25% for 16:9 images. And yeah it will be responsive.

```
.img-wrapper {
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 }

.img-item {
 border: 0 none;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

An extra div is required to wrap the image, with class '.img-wrapper' and class 'image-item' should be give to image itself, in this case like

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<img class="Image" src="http://somewhere.image2.jpg" alt="Image from google" class="img-item">
<div>
```